# How to implement count sql query by my multiple columns and one of them is constant?

Tags: sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

I have following method and it is working. But It doesn't work if I remove `@Query` annotation.

```
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
...
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyRow, UUID> {
     @Query("select count(*) cnt from myrow where my_job_id = :jobId and to_delete = true")
     int getRowsCountByToDeleteTrueAndMyJobId(UUID jobId);
```

I tried to ask google about it but I wasn't abe to ask properly I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int countByJobIdAndToDeleteIsTrue(UUID jobId)` should do the trick.

Comment: I have aleardy provided the solution you offer here to OP. Also check how `@Query` is defined as by default as the OP uses it, it does not refer to jdbc but jpa layer

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos: Your answer suggests `countByToDeleteTrueAndMyJobId()` whereas Jens' answer suggests `countByJobIdAndToDeleteIsTrue()`. Is there a functional or meaningful difference between these? If I'm understanding your answer correctly, there isn't, since Spring is parsing the method name to correspond to generate a query by convention. But, to do so, they still need to update their field names to match their method syntax. Is that right?

Comment: @JeremyCaney correct, you should update field names and also there should not be any difference between the two name versions provided by Jens Schauder and me

Comment: @Jens I see error:
**Null return value from advice does not match primitive return type for....**

Comment: can you post the full stack trace and the executed SQL statement in you question?

Comment: The query is:

`SELECT ...field list withou any count..
FROM "myrow" WHERE "myrow"."to_delete" = TRUE AND ("myrow"."my_job_id " = ?)`

Comment: trace is
http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2022/01/17/0005/3037/338909/09/76723763b1.jpg

Comment: @Jens Schauder any news ?

Answer (score 1):

> "select count(*) cnt from myrow where my_job_id = :jobId and to_delete
> = true"

This means that you have an entity named `myrow` which has some class fields named `my_job_id` and `to_delete`.

Spring Data which offers JPA support will mess the underscores `_` that you have used in the class fields, because it understands the `_` as a separator for multiple fields when used in the name of the method.

So firstly you need to refactor your code so that

- `to_delete` field is renamed into `toDelete`
- `my_job_id` field is renamed into `myJobId`

Then Spring Data will be able to understand a method with the following name

```
int countByToDeleteTrueAndMyJobId(UUID jobId);
```

without the need of `@Query` as it will be built by spring automatically from the name of the method.

Comment: My names are already correspond the naming convention you ask. I use underscores for database columns. camelCase for class fields

Comment: @gstackoverflow if this is the case then the `@Query` in your question is wrong as it should be a native query. As you have it in your question it is not a native query.

Comment: sorry but why not ? It works and works correctly. I use underscores inside Query annotation because in the database I have columns with undesrcores.

Comment: @gstackoverflow check the annotation `@Query` it has the default setting `nativeQuery = false` . So if this is the case your query refers to a JPA query not a database query. So what you write in the query refers to your java classes and not in database!

Comment: @PanagiotisBougioukos The OP is asking about Spring Data JDBC not Spring Data JPA.